# Cannot instantiate router [consistent-hashing-pool], defined in [/IO-DNS/inet-address] error in akka/spray

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am trying create a sample akka/spray project from [here](https://github.com/gagnechris/SprayApiDemo)

While the code compiles successfully in sbt, `sbt run` command throws me an error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate router [consistent-hashin
g-pool], defined in [/IO-DNS/inet-address], make sure it extends [akka.routing.R
outerConfig] and has constructor with [com.typesafe.config.Config] parameter`

the same code compiles and runs successfully in IntelliJ Idea IDE.

EDIT:

Scala version I am using is 2.11 and related libraries
Akka version. 2.4.0 and spray 1.3.3

Comment: What do you have in your application.conf ?

Comment: Same as from the github link

Answer (score 1):

Yes , this is occurred if you are using akka version below 2.5.4 , because for lower version need to configure routing , Please follow the link http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/routing.html for routing in lower version . If you can upgrade the version onwards 2.5.4 then no need to routing.